# When using SVD how do I unsort the scale factors along Sigma's diagonal?

Tags: opencv, math, numpy, computer-vision, svd

I'm not entirely sure how I should phrase this question. Forgive my lack of expertise on the subject. Here is my best shot:

I have a lower triangular transformation matrix

```
A = [(a, 0),
     (c, d)]
```

this matrix maps points on a unit circle to an ellipse.

I want to get some information about the extent of this ellipse so I decomposed the matrix using svd:

```
U, S, V = svd(A)
```

My intuition says that S will have reasonably good approximations the the extent in the x and y direction.

```
S = [(x, 0),
     (0, y)]
```

I have been using S[0,0] as my x-extent and S[1, 1] as my y-extent. And this works reasonably well about half the time: when the x-extent is larger than the y-extent. I found out that the reason is because the implimentations of svd I've tried (cv2.SVDecomp, and numpy.linalg.svd) sort the elements on the diagonal of S. It also seems like this is a relatively standard thing to do.

My question is if there is any way to always have S[0,0] correspond to the scale factor in the x-direction and S[1,1] correspond to the scale factor in the y-direction.

This will become very important later on because when I'll need to recombine my SVD matrixes and I don't want my result matrixes to be permutations of my input matrixes.

How do I work around this? Can I simply swap the rows and columns of U, S, and V if(a > d)? 
Could I test if abs(U[0,0]) < abs(U[0, 1])? or if abs(V[0,0]) < abs(V[0, 1])?

It seems like one of those would work, but I can't prove it to myself for general cases and I really want to knick this problem in the butt.

I was playing with some examples earlier. The Input: is my A matrix. The lines below the input are U * S * V = A'

```
+----
Input: [[ 0.5  0. ] 
        [ 1.   0.5]]

[[ 0.383 -0.924]  * [[ 1.207  0.   ]  * [[ 0.924  0.383]  = [[  5.000e-01   5.551e-17] 
 [ 0.924  0.383]]    [ 0.     0.207]]    [-0.383  0.924]]    [  1.000e+00   5.000e-01]]
---
+----
Input: [[ 1.   0. ] 
        [ 1.   0.5]]

[[ 0.662 -0.75 ]  * [[ 1.46   0.   ]  * [[ 0.966  0.257]  = [[ 1.   0. ] 
 [ 0.75   0.662]]    [ 0.     0.342]]    [-0.257  0.966]]    [ 1.   0.5]]
---
+----
Input: [[ 1.5  0. ] 
        [ 1.   0.5]]

[[ 0.811 -0.585]  * [[ 1.825  0.   ]  * [[ 0.987  0.16 ]  = [[  1.500e+00   2.776e-17] 
 [ 0.585  0.811]]    [ 0.     0.411]]    [-0.16   0.987]]    [  1.000e+00   5.000e-01]]
---
+----
Input: [[ 0.5  0. ] 
        [ 0.8  0.8]]

[[ 0.324 -0.946]  * [[ 1.19   0.   ]  * [[ 0.772  0.636]  = [[ 0.5  0. ] 
 [ 0.946  0.324]]    [ 0.     0.336]]    [-0.636  0.772]]    [ 0.8  0.8]]
---
+----
Input: [[ 1.   0. ] 
        [ 0.8  0.8]]

[[ 0.643 -0.766]  * [[ 1.397  0.   ]  * [[ 0.899  0.438]  = [[  1.000e+00   5.551e-17] 
 [ 0.766  0.643]]    [ 0.     0.573]]    [-0.438  0.899]]    [  8.000e-01   8.000e-01]]
---
+----
Input: [[ 1.5  0. ] 
        [ 0.8  0.8]]

[[ 0.829 -0.559]  * [[ 1.749  0.   ]  * [[ 0.967  0.256]  = [[ 1.5  0. ] 
 [ 0.559  0.829]]    [ 0.     0.686]]    [-0.256  0.967]]    [ 0.8  0.8]]
---
+----
Input: [[ 0.5  0. ] 
        [ 0.6  1.1]]

[[ 0.212 -0.977]  * [[ 1.279  0.   ]  * [[ 0.541  0.841]  = [[ 0.5  0. ] 
 [ 0.977  0.212]]    [ 0.     0.43 ]]    [-0.841  0.541]]    [ 0.6  1.1]]
---
+----
Input: [[ 1.   0. ] 
        [ 0.6  1.1]]

[[ 0.534 -0.845]  * [[ 1.396  0.   ]  * [[ 0.746  0.666]  = [[  1.000e+00   5.551e-17] 
 [ 0.845  0.534]]    [ 0.     0.788]]    [-0.666  0.746]]    [  6.000e-01   1.100e+00]]
---
+----
Input: [[ 1.5  0. ] 
        [ 0.6  1.1]]

[[ 0.823 -0.569]  * [[ 1.695  0.   ]  * [[ 0.929  0.369]  = [[  1.500e+00   1.110e-16] 
 [ 0.569  0.823]]    [ 0.     0.974]]    [-0.369  0.929]]    [  6.000e-01   1.100e+00]]
---
+----
Input: [[ 0.5  0. ] 
        [ 0.4  1.4]]

[[ 0.105 -0.994]  * [[ 1.463  0.   ]  * [[ 0.308  0.951]  = [[ 0.5  0. ] 
 [ 0.994  0.105]]    [ 0.     0.478]]    [-0.951  0.308]]    [ 0.4  1.4]]
---
+----
Input: [[ 1.   0. ] 
        [ 0.4  1.4]]

[[ 0.305 -0.952]  * [[ 1.499  0.   ]  * [[ 0.458  0.889]  = [[ 1.   0. ] 
 [ 0.952  0.305]]    [ 0.     0.934]]    [-0.889  0.458]]    [ 0.4  1.4]]
---
+----
Input: [[ 1.5  0. ] 
        [ 0.4  1.4]]

[[ 0.744 -0.668]  * [[ 1.67   0.   ]  * [[ 0.828  0.56 ]  = [[  1.500e+00   1.110e-16] 
 [ 0.668  0.744]]    [ 0.     1.258]]    [-0.56   0.828]]    [  4.000e-01   1.400e+00]]
---
+----
Input: [[ 0.5  0. ] 
        [ 0.2  1.7]]

[[ 0.037 -0.999]  * [[ 1.713  0.   ]  * [[ 0.128  0.992]  = [[ 0.5  0. ] 
 [ 0.999  0.037]]    [ 0.     0.496]]    [-0.992  0.128]]    [ 0.2  1.7]]
---
+----
Input: [[ 1.   0. ] 
        [ 0.2  1.7]]

[[ 0.102 -0.995]  * [[ 1.718  0.   ]  * [[ 0.175  0.985]  = [[  1.000e+00  -2.776e-17] 
 [ 0.995  0.102]]    [ 0.     0.99 ]]    [-0.985  0.175]]    [  2.000e-01   1.700e+00]]
---
+----
Input: [[ 1.5  0. ] 
        [ 0.2  1.7]]

[[ 0.354 -0.935]  * [[ 1.745  0.   ]  * [[ 0.411  0.911]  = [[  1.500e+00  -1.110e-16] 
 [ 0.935  0.354]]    [ 0.     1.462]]    [-0.911  0.411]]    [  2.000e-01   1.700e+00]]
---
```

It seems like A' is always equal to A, so I don't think I have to worry about re combinations giving me permutations. It also seems like it is always the case that when abs(V[0,1]) > abs(V[0, 0]) that the x and y extents have been swapped in the S matrix. Is this always true? Can anyone give me an example of when it is not true?

---

Thanks two both of the answers bellow I've have understood how to write a solution to my problem. Here is the code I wrote for any other wanderers who stumble upon this

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from numpy import (array, sin, cos, sqrt)


def svd(M):
    # V is actually Vt
    flags = cv2.SVD_FULL_UV
    S, U, Vt = cv2.SVDecomp(M, flags=flags)
    s = S.flatten()
    return U, s, Vt


def get_UsVt_list(M_list):
    UsV_list = [svd(M) for M in M_list]
    return UsV_list


def get_USVt_list(M_list):
    UsV_list = get_UsVt_list(M_list)
    USV_list = [(U, np.diag(s), V) for U, s, V in UsV_list]
    return USV_list


def USVt_axis_extent(U, S, Vt):
    return sqrt(U.dot(S) ** 2).T.sum(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the singular values proportional to the length of principal axes that may or may not be oriented along x, y. Check U to see how they are oriented. Its columns show the coordinate of those axes.

The beauty of SVD is that it can be applied to any matrix  **A=USV<sup>T</sup>**  and its components have this meaning:

**V<sup>T</sup>** - rotation matrix that rotates a circle (rotates its point vectors) to orient them properly for the next scaling operation. In other words circle remains a circle but data points slide along it (getting **re-mapped**) to orient them properly for the next operation. For example, if vector 1, 1 is to be squeezed it is better be aligned with 0, 1
**S** - scaling that always happens along x, y (this means x coordinates are scaled by sigmaX and y coordinates are scaled by sigmaY); thus it was important to pre-rotate data in case scaling is need to be done not at X, Y axis directions but at a different directions; it is like you know you are gonna get **squeezed** and you turn your side towards that force; note that after scaling the circle now turned into an ellipse with its axes oriented along x, y axis; For example, we may expand at x direction (coordinate) by factor 1.5 and squeeze at y direction by 0.9;
**U** - We may want the ellipse to be **oriented** at angle to x, y axis and the last rotation matrix U does exactly that. It rotates the ellipse to get it a certain desired orientation. For example, its longest axis may be rotated 45 deg. to point in the direction 1, 1 instead of original 1, 0.

To sum up SVD represents any matrix multiplication as 3 consecutive operations: **remap, squeeze, orient**. A nice color illustration of this process can be found here: [Analyze1SVD.pdf](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/s.prince/book/AppCPDF.zip) (it is deep in the directory structure of the unpacked folder).

Answer (score 1):

The V matrix of the SVD decomposition A = U * S * V', where the ' symbol indicates transposition, encodes the permutation of the axes of A. You can think of it as the coordinate transform that maps the original (x, y, z, ...) coordinate axes to the principal directions of the transformation A.